# Navigating to a viewcontroller in storyboard always creates a new ViewController, how can I reuse the previous ViewController?

Tags: ios, navigation, storyboard

I have a Navigation app. The root view controller (`RootViewController`) has a button that navigates to another view controller (`DetailViewController1`). It is very easy to do it in XCode storyboard.

My problem is : `DetailViewController1` always create a new instance when I navigate to it. While I tried another way, I created another `DetailViewController2` class and create its instance when the app start. Then I write code to push the DetailViewController2 instance, in this case, the `DetailViewController2` is only be created once.

The question is : Is there a setting on storyboard so that I can prevent creating the same view controller instance when navigating to it? Just like I push the manually created `DetailViewController2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. The only way to push always the same instance is to perform the push from code, as you have already done.

Comment: I see, I want to make sure if I missed something. Thanks.

Comment: That's right. The reason for this is that by default iOS destroys a UIViewController when you go back from it, so that it releases the memory it was using. Retaining the address of a ViewController this way is not recommended as it can create a retain cycle resulting in memory wastage.

Answer (score 1):

Set a story board id for viewcontroller . Then in button Action

```
    myViewController* vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboardid"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```